# Asp.net WebAPI Gives error No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

My application is a classic Asp.Net application and not MVC. Now i want to add ApiController to it.

I have added following API Controller

```
public class AlfrescoController : ApiController
{
    [System.Web.Http.Route("api/alfresco")]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/<controller>/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    // POST api/<controller>
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
    }
}
```

My routing code in Global.asax is like below,

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
              name: "DefaultApi",
              routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
              defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }
              );

}
```

Now when i try to request http://localhost:52182/api/alfresco/, it gives me following error,

> This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
>   
>   
>   No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:52182/api/alfresco/'.
>   
>   
>   No type was found that matches the controller named 'alfresco'.

Please let me know if i am doing anything wrong here, i have tried all the solutions from stackoverflow, nothing seems to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change code in Global.asax.cs to:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(Register);
}

public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(); //Will have preference over the default route below

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

"MapHttpAttributeRoutes" is an extension method available in the Nuget Package: "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core". So you will have to install that first.